# Weird nested structural type in generics

Tags: scala, scalaz, structural-typing

Can someone explain weird construction of structural type nested in generics:

```
implicit def Function1Functor[R]: Functor[({type λ[α]=(R) => α})#λ] = 
  new Functor[({type λ[α]=(R) => α})#λ] ....
```

This example comes from Scalaz library: [Functor.scala](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc.sxr/scalaz/Functor.scala.html#14966)

Why this construction is needed there? Wouldn't be simpler to write:

```
 implicit def Function1Functor[R,A]: Functor[R =>A]
```

or

```
 implicit def Function1Functor[R,A]: Functor[Function1[R,A]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of the `Functor` type constructor shows that it is parameterised with another, unary, type constructor `F`:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] extends InvariantFunctor[F]
```

Neither `R => A` nor `Function1[R,A]` are type constructors; they take no parameters.

However in:

```
type λ[α] = (R) => α
```

`λ` is a type constructor taking one parameter, `α`. (`R` is already defined in this context.)

The syntax `({type λ[α]=(R) => α})#λ` is known as a type lambda. It is a syntactic trick allowing a type alias to be created inline and referred to via a projection, so the whole expression can be used where a type is required.