# Function Functor in Scala

Tags: scala, functor

On my way to learn about Functors in Scala, I came across the Function Functor and I have 2 questions around it:

1. What is this signature in the Functor type argument for Function1?

> ```
> implicit def Function1Functor[R]: Functor[({type l[a]=(R) => a})#l] = new Functor[({type l[a]=(R) => a})#l] {
>   def fmap[A, B](r: R => A, f: A => B) = r andThen f
> }
> ```

2. Without even writing the Function1Functor, I was able to do the following from an sbt console:

> (x: Int) => x * 2 map (_ * 2)

How should this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See [Weird nested structural type in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243680/weird-nested-structural-type-in-generics)
2. Feels strange:

   ```
   scala> (x: Int) => x * 2 map (_ * 2)
   <console>:11: error: value map is not a member of Int
     (x: Int) => x * 2 map (_ * 2)
                    ^

   scala> { (x: Int) => x * 2 } map (_ * 2)
   <console>:11: error: value map is not a member of Int => Int
    { (x: Int) => x * 2 } map (_ * 2)
   ```

   If the latter works for you, maybe your SBT console automatically imports Scalaz features; inspect your build.sbt for a line such as

   ```
   initialCommands in console := "import scalaz._, Scalaz._"
   ```

   By the way, the console should provide you with a hint on the actual type

   ```
   scala> {(x: Int) => x * 2} map (_ * 2)
   res1: Int => Int = scalaz.std.FunctionInstances$$anon$3$$Lambda$1884/1646077266@29e39141
   ```

   If you want to inspect the implicit resolution process, you may toggle the following option, e.g., in build.sbt:

   ```
   scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlog-implicits")
   ```